# how to find matrix A from complete solution to Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am trying to solve a problem. I was stuck.Any help is appreciated.

The complete solution to  $Ax=\left[\begin{array}[c]{rr}1 \\3 \end{array}\right]$ is 
$ x= \left[\begin{array}[c]{rr}1\\0\end{array}\right]+ c \left[\begin{array}[c]{rr}0\\1\end{array}\right].$ Find Matrix A.

Comment: hint: $Ax$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so choosing $ A= \left[\begin{array}[c]{rr}a_1 & a_2\\a_3 & a_4\end{array}\right]$ then i get two equations $ a_1+ca_2=1,  a_3+ca_4=3 $. now do I have to fix values for $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4 ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Write up $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ and use the deduced equations $$\begin{align} A\pmatrix{1\\0}\ &=\ \pmatrix{1\\3} \\[3pt]
A\pmatrix{0\\1}\ &=\ \pmatrix{0\\0} \,.
\end{align}$$